# C# Dictionary Pivoting Linq

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, dynamic

I've a Dictionary like this:

```
Key | Value
C1  | 1
C2  | 2
C3  | 3
```

Now I need some linq statement or lambda expression (or other mechanism) to return new object like this:

```
new { C1 = 1, C2 = 2, C3 = 3}.
```

The problem is that the keys' values are known only at runtime, as I know only at runtime how many properies my new anonimous object has and their names.

Can anyone suggest me how reach my goal?

Comment: How are you going to use the anonymous object if you do not know the propertynames?

Answer (score 8):

You can use a combination of an [ExpandoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx) and [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx).

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, int> {
    { "C1", 1},
    { "C2", 2},
    { "C3", 3}
};
var expandoObject = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
foreach (var kvp in data) {
    expandoObject.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
dynamic pivotedData = expandoObject;

Console.WriteLine(pivotedData.C1);
Console.WriteLine(pivotedData.C2);
Console.WriteLine(pivotedData.C3);
Console.ReadLine();
```

This will yield:

```
1
2
3
```

You can probably make a nice extension method out of it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible... You can't use the result object if you don't know its properties at compile time, without jumping through Reflection hoops (it would be easier to use the dictionary).

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Edited to correct (and thank you for commenting :) )